# Using spring applicationContext in many classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

is it possible to use spring applicationcontext in many classes?

---

For example
**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        Server s = (Server) ctx.getBean("server");
        try{
            s.start();
        }catch(Exception ek){ ek.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

---

**EndPoint.java**

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/server")
public class EndPoint{
    List<Room> rooms = ..............
    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message, Session s){
        return message;
    }
}
```

---

**spring.xml**

```
   <bean id="server" class="org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server">
       <constructor-arg index="0" value="localhost"/>
       <constructor-arg index="1" value="8025"/>
       <constructor-arg index="2" value="/margonem"/>
       <constructor-arg index="3"><null /></constructor-arg>
       <constructor-arg index="4" value="com.berrigan.margonemserver.EndPoint"></constructor-arg>
   </bean>
```

The main problem is that room list should be initialized using spring. Unfortunately I cannot pass it through constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use multiple contexts, but I wouldn't advise it if you want objects to inter-operate across those. You'll end up with multiple singletons (confusingly)

If you can't find a way to perform your injection via Spring, I would perhaps give your application context global static scope, and set the rooms list via a `ctx.getBean("rooms")` invocation. Having a global static application context isn't ideal, but perhaps a practical solution in the absence of any hooks for injection.

Comment: I cannot vote up, but thanks a lot. Propably static applicationcontext is best way.